# Trigger opacity 0 to 1 smoothly on a div at 400px scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

Hey there:) I'm having some trouble with a function that I want to execute when someone scrolls to 400px. I would like a headers background-color to first show at 400px, while it smoothly reveals it from 0 to 1 opacity.

I have have made something that does most of what I want:P but starts instantly when i start scrolling.

And is it possible to make it stay fully revealed if you update the browser after du reached further than 400px?

Cheers!

```
HTML:

<header class="header">
    <div class="header-bg">Logo</div>
</header>

CSS:
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
z-index: 3;
color: #fff;
}

.header-bg {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 1);
opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var divFade = $('.header-bg');
$(document).ready(function() {
    divFade.css('opacity', 0);
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var percent = $(document).scrollTop() / (400);
    divFade.css('opacity', percent);  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think you need something like this:

CSS:

```
body{
    height: 2000px;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 1);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    divFade = $(".header-bg");

    var toggleHeader = function (noAnimate) {

        var threshold  = 400,
            fadeLength = 300,
            opacity,
            scrollTop  = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop < threshold) {
            opacity = 0;
        } else if (scrollTop > threshold + fadeLength) {
            opacity = 1;
        } else {
            if (noAnimate) {
                opacity = 1;
            } else {
                opacity = (scrollTop - threshold) / fadeLength;
            }
        }

        divFade.css("opacity", opacity);

    };

    toggleHeader(true);
    $(window).scroll(function () {toggleHeader();});

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xa86d31m/1/

Comment: It triggers the event at 400px, but it snaps to that position aswell:( Plus it works like Jquery fadeIn(). Can it be made to progressively change when you scroll, so it reveals gradually when you scroll :)??

Comment: Just perfect mate! Any change you could explain me what is going on? Nonetheless you get some deserved points:D Thank you!

Comment: Any change that that you could explain how I make it 0.8 in max opacity? I tried change the "1" opacity value to 0.8 in the script, but it still makes it to 1 value.

Comment: @user2633561, If you want to declare a range of opacity (something different than 0 and 1), you just have to add  little more math to toggleHeader function. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xa86d31m/3/. I've added some comments for you.

Comment: Hope it is okay to ask again >< And thanks for the giant help. But how do I target 2 tags. Lets say I want to only make the header-bg opacity 0.8 but the logo 1 in opacity. Is that even possible?

Comment: @user2633561, Everything is possible with JS. You should create a jQuery plugin and define maxOpacity as an attribute. How to create a plugin: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.